# C# Logging in to a website with cookies

Tags: c#, http, cookies, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I've been trying to get my program to log in to a website for a few days now, to no avail. I believe I have a good bit of it correct (particularly the format of the data that needs to be posted).

However, I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what problem I'm having. The website requires cookies to authenticate the login and I'm not sure how to handle cookies. I've tried following so many google results that it's silly, and yet none of them do a great job of explaining what it is that I need to know.

To achieve this log in, I'm using HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse. The code I'm using is mostly put together from other Stack Overflow questions that did not solve my problem. What this means, essentially, is that I do not fully understand the process required to log into a website with HTTP. I do have Fiddler installed, and I have also used the Chrome developers tools to monitor network traffic and compare my POST to that of the website.

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace FormPOSTing
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // URL of the login form and the data that needs to be posted
            string formURL = "https://www.pogo.com/action/pogo/login.do";
            string postData = "screenname=" + "Username" + "&password=" + "Password" + "&remember_password_hidden=" + "true" + "&signin=" + "Sign in";
            byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(formURL);
            request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
            request.KeepAlive = true;
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;

            using (Stream postStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
            }

            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        }
    }
```

Now, What's happening is the URI that the page is returning is this page:
http://pogo.com/error/no-cookies.jsp

It doesn't matter what the username and password is because it always returns that page. It never gets to the point where it can attempt to log in.

Could someone give me more insight on how this works and how to achieve a successful login?

Answer (score 0):

You have to persist your cookie jar `CookieContainer` across requests.  Each time your cookie jar is destroyed all the cookies in it are destroyed too.  Right now you have tied the lifetime of your jar to the lifetime of a single request.

Correct it like so:

```
namespace FormPOSTing
{
    class Program
    {
        static CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
        static void Main(string[] args)
            request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
        }
    }
}
```